# CodeIgniter : How to retrieve ajax jquery data passed through window.location.href in new controller

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, controller

CodeIgniter : How to retrieve ajax jquery data passed through `window.location.href` in new controller ?

```
$(".x").on("click","a.p",function(){       
            productId =  $(this).attr("productId");        
            alert("product ID : " + productId); 
            $.ajax({
               url: 'home/allProductDetails',
               type: 'POST',
               data: {
                 'productId'  : productId
               },
               success: function (dat) {

                    var result = eval('(' + dat + ')');
                    if (result.success == true)
                    {   
                        if(result.data.length>0)
                        {//alert("Success");window.location.href = "newControllerName" + "?result=" + result.data;
                         }
                    }
```

on ajax success, the data is passed to the new controller using window.location.href

Comment: How you use in PHP . `$_GET['result']`

Comment: I think you when you want to retrieve/fetch data always use GET method

Comment: Thank You Narendra and Aldrin27

Comment: How can i split the array data retrieved through $_GET['result']

Comment: while retrieving the array data, result is obtained as x,y,z,a,b,c,l,m,n instead of x,y,z  (1st array); a,b,c (2nd array) and l,m,n (3rd array)

Comment: If you want it to be at every third position than simply use `$result = array_chunk($your_array,3); print_r($result); `

Comment: currently, console.log("result.data" + result.data); // displays as result.data 16,1308150848477.jpg,7.jpg,1308150848477.jpg,17,130815084901IMG_2253.JPG,IMG_2253.JPG,130815084901IMG_2253.JPG. Its basically 2 arrays i.e "16,1308150848477.jpg,7.jpg,1308150848477.jpg" and "7,130815084901IMG_2253.JPG,IMG_2253.JPG,130815084901IMG_2253.JPG". On passing this data through window.location.href, in controller the data is fetched as follows : $imageResult = $_GET['result']; echo $imageResult; // displays as a single line with no array separation

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

**Ajax:**

```
$(".x").on("click","a.p",function(){       
   productId =  $(this).attr("productId");        
   alert("product ID : " + productId); 
   $.ajax({
      url: 'home/allProductDetails',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
        'productId'  : productId
      },
      success: function (dat) {

         var result = eval('(' + dat + ')');
         if (result.success == true)
         {   
            if(result.data.length>0)
            {
               //alert("Success");
               window.location.href = "newControllerName/methodName/" + result.data;
            }
         }
   });
});
```

**Controller:**

```
function methodName($data)
{
    //here you can access `$data` variable   
    print_r($data); 
}
```

This can work try it...

Comment: By default in the newControllerName, index function is accessed. How can we send the data then

Comment: data cannot be passed by appending '/'

Comment: `/` takes next thing as method and then next as argument so plz check my updated answer.....